# The connection between the solution set $\{F^{\nu}=0\}$ being invariant under a Lie group action and $DF$ having full rank

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Suppose we have a function $F:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^l$ from a smooth $m$-manifold $M$ to $\mathbb{R}^l$, where $l\le m$. If we denote the components of $F$ by $F^{\nu}$, we can define a system of $l$ equations:

$$F^{\nu}(x)=0.\tag{1}$$
for $\nu=1,\ldots,l$.

Let $G$ be a (connected local) Lie group of transformations on $M$, suppose we want to find the condition for the solution set $(1)$ to be invariant under $G$. Note that $F$ itself need not be $G$-invariant. I would naively expect that the solution set to $(1)$ would be invariant iff $w(F^{\nu})=0$ for every infinitesimal generator $w$ of $G$, since (representing the exponential map as $e^{\epsilon w}$)
$$F^{\nu}(e^{\epsilon w}x)=F^{\nu}(x)+w(F^{\nu})(x)\epsilon+o(\epsilon),\tag{2}$$
and so
$$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}F^{\nu}(e^{\epsilon w}x)\right\rvert_{\epsilon=0}=w(F^{\nu})(x).\tag{3}$$
The left hand side will be zero iff the right hand side is.

However, it turns out (Theorem 2.8 in Olver's "[Applications of Lie Groups to Differential Equations](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387950006)") that in addition to $(3)$ you also need the differential $DF$ to have maximum rank (on the solution set $(1)$). Could someone please tell me what I'm missing that makes (1-3) invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $$\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon}F^{\nu}(e^{\epsilon w}x)\right\rvert_{\epsilon=0}=0$$ at the point $x$ alone isn't enough to guarantee that $F^\nu(e^{\epsilon w}x)=0$ for $\epsilon > 0,$ so as written your argument only shows that this condition is necessary, not sufficient. It shouldn't be too surprising that we need a full-rank assumption to make both directions work - this is exactly the assumption we need to invoke something like the implicit function theorem in order to "straighten out" $F$. In particular, it implies that any $w$ with $w(F^\nu)=0$ is tangent to some level curve of $F^\nu,$ which is probably part of your mental picture.

You can try thinking about some examples: the most obvious would be something like $F(x) = x^2,$ where the solution set is $\{ 0 \}.$ Any group of transformations that moves this point (e.g. the translations) is then a counterexample, since $DF|_0 = 0.$

Comment: Thanks very much, that was very helpful.